# Restore large sized directories using linux command

Tags: linux

I want to restore the files inside the directory which is deleted and I want to use linux. So I am using "cp -ra".

Now large sized directory are getting restored back using "cp -ra" (less than 10MB) but the files inside the directory are not restoring using "cp -ra". Plesae help whats the unix command if anyone has any idea.

Comment: AFAIK, if you rm from command line, you can't restore the files, because they don't go to Trash. They are totally removed instead. You can move them to trash when you're deleting, but that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

`cp` can't restore deleted files. If restoration of deleted files is possible at all depends on the file system these files were stored in.